# Unable to download dependency files from GitHub

Tags: php, github

I am successful for installing composer and `xampp with PHP version 7.1.8` but I am unable to download files whenever I run command I got the `[InvalidArgumentException]` error every time, I don't know how to download all required files or resolve this issue.

Here is the complete error

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\test>composer require Majestcx/OpenLoad-Downloader

  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package Majestcx/OpenLoad-Downloader at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the p
  ackage spelling or your minimum-stability

require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Comment: It would be downloaded with `composer require Majestcx/OpenLoad-Downloader "4.*"` The reason why it is not working is, There are no releases https://github.com/Majestcx/OpenLoad-Downloader/releases

Comment: @SahilGulati thanks for your answer I tried but still failed `The requested package majestcx/openload-downloader could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.` can you please help me further

Comment: @SahilGulati if it works at your end can you share me the all the downloaded files in zip?

Comment: The reason behind this message is there are no package or releases available with this. You can check this link https://github.com/Majestcx/OpenLoad-Downloader/releases , The thing you can do is try `git clone https://github.com/Majestcx/OpenLoad-Downloader`

Comment: @SahilGulati should I run this command in `cmd`?

Comment: Yes If you are using windows execute in cmd and if you are using ubuntu hit this on terminal. Make sure git is installed.

Comment: @SahilGulati it only copied the files which are on the same URL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154300/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-rtra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide a valid stable version like this

> `composer require Majestcx/OpenLoad-Downloader "4.*"` instead of `composer require Majestcx/OpenLoad-Downloader`

But the current situation is [Majestcx/OpenLoad-Downloader](https://github.com/Majestcx/OpenLoad-Downloader) does not have releases available [Majestcx/OpenLoad-Downloader/releases](https://github.com/Majestcx/OpenLoad-Downloader/releases)

You can do one think:
`Majestcx/OpenLoad-Downloader` is dependent on some external libraries [php-phantomjs](https://packagist.org/packages/jonnyw/php-phantomjs).

So You can do it like:

> **1.** Create a folder lets `MyProject`
>
> **2.** In that directory install `php-phantomjs` with this `composer require jonnyw/php-phantomjs`
>
> **3.** git clone https://github.com/Majestcx/OpenLoad-Downloader

**Update:** As per discussion you were getting

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught JonnyW\PhantomJs\Exception\ProcedureFailedException

and for that client instance you can do it like this for setting the path to your `phantomjs.exe`.

```
$client->getEngine()->setPath(dirname(FILE).'/bin/phantomjs.exe');
```

[Reference](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs/issues/19) link for solving this exception.